# Issue while deploy the cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am new to GCP. I created a cloud function and tried to deploy it. I encountered the following error while deploying. Can anyone help me solve this issue? Thank you!

```
Command: 
gcloud functions deploy first_cloud_function_http --runtime python37 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --verbosity debug

Error Logs:
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.functions.deploy] with arguments: [--allow-unauthenticated: "True", --runtime: "python37", --trigger-http: "True", --verbosity: "debug", NAME: "first_cloud_function_http"]
INFO: Not using ignore file.
INFO: Not using ignore file.
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                                                                            
DEBUG: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=Failed to initialize region (action ID: 78ed38913711b6cd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hasher/GN/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/home/hasher/GN/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 808, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/home/hasher/GN/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 351, in Run
    return _Run(args, track=self.ReleaseTrack())
  File "/home/hasher/GN/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 305, in _Run
    on_every_poll=[TryToLogStackdriverURL])
  File "/home/hasher/GN/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 318, in CatchHTTPErrorRaiseHTTPExceptionFn
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hasher/GN/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 369, in WaitForFunctionUpdateOperation
    on_every_poll=on_every_poll)
  File "/home/hasher/GN/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 151, in Wait
    on_every_poll)
  File "/home/hasher/GN/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 121, in _WaitForOperation
    sleep_ms=SLEEP_MS)
  File "/home/hasher/GN/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 219, in RetryOnResult
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hasher/GN/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 73, in _GetOperationStatus
    raise exceptions.FunctionsError(OperationErrorToString(op.error))
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.functions.exceptions.FunctionsError: OperationError: code=13, message=Failed to initialize region (action ID: 78ed38913711b6cd)
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=Failed to initialize region (action ID: 78ed38913711b6cd)
```

Comment: You haven’t specified the region in your command.

Comment: That sounds like the beginning of a good answer @Johan, especially if you can then include an example of how to pass the region into the call. :)

Comment: Thank you Frank. I was during the time I wrote the comment unable to elaborate more, but wanted to give a nudge in the right direction for anyone else eager to pick up the ball :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that as stated on the documentation of the [gcloud functions deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy) command you'd necessarily need to set the `--region` flag.

To check the available regions where Cloud Functions is available refer to the following [sections of the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations).

For example, if you'd like to deploy the function in the `europe-west1` region running the following command would suffice:

```
gcloud functions deploy first_cloud_function_http --region europe-west1 --runtime python37 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --verbosity debug
```

Additionally, if you'd like to avoid using the `--region` flag you can [set a default region](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations#setting_a_default_region) for Cloud Functions by running:

```
gcloud config set functions/region REGION
```

where you could change the `REGION` field to any of the [locations mentioned above](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations).